# Function doesn't work in Javascript (increase/decrease button)

Tags: javascript, html, function

I want to make increase/decrease button work when I click the button. I put the  section in JavaScript(using as part of a function to insert into HTML file), but it doesn't work. The code in JavaScript is as below:

```
string ="<img class='minubtn' src='images/delete.png' onclick='javascript: 
document.getElementById('countNo1').value--;' />"+
"<input type='text'  id='countNo1'  class='txtCount' value='0' placeholder='0'/>"+
"<img class='addbtn' src='images/add.png' onclick='javascript: 
document.getElementById('countNo1').value++;'/>"
```

I find the reason why it's not working. In nested string, I need to use \' \' instead of '' to quote the  id. So the code should like this:

```
string ="<img class='minubtn' src='images/delete.png' onclick='javascript: 
document.getElementById(\'countNo1\').value--;' />"+
"<input type='text'  id='countNo1'  class='txtCount' value='0' placeholder='0'/>"+
"<img class='addbtn' src='images/add.png' onclick='javascript: 
document.getElementById(\'countNo1\').value++;'/>"
```

Comment: will you post HTML code here or in JSFiddle?

Comment: The HTML code is just <div id="divTmp1"></div>. The js function is to get the data through API and append to this div dynamically. The   other code works well, just the increase/decrease part doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

This might help you

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="count" value="0" id="count">
<input type="button" value="+1" onclick="operate('add')">
<input type="button" value="-1" onclick="operate('dec')">
```

Script:

```
    <script>
    function operate(val){
    if(val == "add"){
       var val = document.getElementById('count').value;
       val++;
       document.getElementById('count').value = val;
    } else{
        var val = document.getElementById('count').value;
        val--;
        document.getElementById('count').value = val;
    }
   }
  </script>
```